# connection to different nodes in infinispan cluster

Tags: infinispan, spring-cache

We have infinispan with 7 nodes in the cluster.

We have a set of clients connecting to three nodes as configured in hotrodclient.properties and another set of clients connecting to remaining nodes in the cluster.

Our objective is to distribute the load on the cluster . Is it ok to do like this ?

Answer (score 1):

The Hot Rod client already performs load balancing by default. Based on the configured intelligence, it performs round-robing or contacts the server which owns the data to be accessed directly.

You have more information on the [documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/hotrod_java/hotrod_java.html#client_intelligence) page (Section 2.3 and 2.3.1).